# Difference in sql queries joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

would like to ask is there any difference between two queries?

```
SELECT TableA., TableB., TableC.* FROM TableA
JOIN TableB
    ON   TableA.aID=  TableB.aID
JOIN TableC
    ON TableB.cID = TableC.cID



SELECT TableA., TableB., TableC.* FROM TableA
JOIN TableB
    ON TableB.aID = TableA.aID
JOIN TableC
    ON TableC.cID = TableB.cID
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: What would be your guess?

Comment: Both return the same result ("invalid syntax").

Comment: Once syntax error is fixed (`TableA.` should be `TableA.*` etc), the `JOIN` condition works the same whether you say `TableA.aID=  TableB.aID` or `TableB.aID = TableA.aID`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference?  Yes, you have reversed the comparisons in the `on` clauses.

Does this affect either the result set or performance?  No.  The logic of the query is exactly the same, so the result set is exactly the same.

As for performance, there is no database where the order of the comparisons would affect the optimization of the query.  From a practical point of view, the two versions should be identical.

Comment: Plus the Optimizer can run your query in any order it actually wants to. Your queries are more like hints than they are descriptive of the plan. With this in mind...focus on what your join is doing, rather than how complicated you can make a query. Why are you doing this? Are you unable to use parenthesis (like math, this does matter) to make the query clearer? What is the actionable result of this query? Head knowledge is nice, but experienced professionals provide value.